# Help find mistake in $\int_0^{π/4} (\cos 2x)^{3/2} \cos(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$ \int_0^{π/4} (\cos 2x)^{3/2} \cos(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

[image]

I was able to find out the correct answer as $\frac{3\pi}{16\sqrt{2}}$ using $t = \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{2}}$ instead of above. But I want to know what mistake I might have done in above method.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please edit your question according to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the third line, you have $2t^4 - t^2 +\frac{1}{2}$, which you have written as $(\sqrt{2}t^2- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2$ in the next line.

But $(\sqrt{2}t^2- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2=2t^4 - 2t^2 +\frac{1}{2}$